# How to Switch between 2 models relationship in another model

Tags: php, laravel

I have the below function to switch between 2 models according to client type to get details, but it always returns with the IndividualDetails clients only

```
class Client extends Model
{
public function details()
    {
        $model = $this->is_company ? CompanyDetails::class : IndividualDetails::class;

        return $this->morphOne($model, 'related');
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that your variable `$this->is_company` returns false everytime

Comment: @LeenaPatel that's right, even if when trying dynamic relationship like adviced still stuck

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this.

You are not guaranteed that the logic will exexute correctly.

if you have `User::class` model that belongs to `Client::class` model, then

```php
User::whereHas('client', fn ($qry) => 
   $qry->whereHas('details', fn($qry) =>
       $qry->where('some_field', 'some-value')
   )
);
```

In this case, the relation `details` on `Client::class` is evaluated before the client model is hydrated. so, `$this->is_company` is not set when the return value of the `details` method is evaluated.

In short. Do not do this!